# Iterating over a kendo datasource returned from JayData

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, datasource, jaydata

I'm trying to iterate over data returned by JayData into a kendo datasource object.

I have code similar to this

```
var clients = database.Clients.asKendoDataSource();
var clientData = clients.data();

for (var index = 0; index < clientData.length; index++)
{
    ....
}
```

The database is IndexedDb

The problem is that length is always 0 and no data is in clientData.

When I bind the datasource clients to a Kendo listview however, I get records and inspecting the result of clients._data shows that it has been populated with data.

I've tried calling clients.fetch() with no luck.  How can I get the datasource populated with data so that I can iterate over it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `clientData.total()` to get the number of items in the Kendo UI dataSource? \[[Reference](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#methods-total)\]

Comment: I haven't tried that, but i'll give it a go tonight.  I just don't understand why it only works when bound.  I'm thinking that there is a method on the datasource that I need to call in order for it to request the data from the table.

Comment: Try `clientsData.read()` to request data from the server.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions.  I didn't realized that it was async. I was originally simply calling fetch() expecting that it would return once it had all the data but in fact it is async so you need to pass in a callback, as in, fetch(function(){ data will now be available });  I suspect the same is true for when calling read().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I didn't realized that it was async. I was originally simply calling fetch() expecting that it would return once it had all the data but in fact it is async so you need to pass in a callback, as in, fetch(function(){ data will now be available }); I suspect the same is true for when calling read().